# EC2 yum sometimes not working User Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

I'm having such a weird behaviour with my EC2 lately. Sometimes (not all the times), when my autoscaling group create a new EC2, the EC2 cannot run its User Data because yum is broken, and can't fetch anything.

But I can still connect to SSH to my EC2, run the User Data myself and suddently everything is working fine. Which means it's not likely to be a proxy problem (I think so).

This is the trace I have from /var/log/cloud-init-out :
[logs](https://justpaste.it/5t7dv)

(Sorry for the link, but when i tried to copy into Stack, it was all messed up..)

If you have any idea

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The logs shows:

`Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn2-core/2/x86_64 Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://amazonlinux.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list error was 12: Timeout on http://amazonlinux.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list: (28, 'Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds')`

So `user_data` execution fails because `yum` fails because the connection to the repository timed out. That's the problem.

If this happens frequently and as this is a aws hosted repository I would rule out the repo being frequently not available and start looking for problems in your aws environment.

However with the information provided one can only guess what could be the issue here. How are the instances in the ASG running the user_data scripts connected to the internet? Maybe there is a NAT-Gateway or firewall in between causing issues with the connection to the repo.

The most reliable and fastest way to enable a auto-scaling group to scale up is a custom `AMI` and install those packages in the AMI. That makes the process more resilient to failures of 3. party services.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help ! To give you more information, my EC2 are in a private subnet and using a NAT-Gateway to connect to the internet (I've routed my NAT to the subnet). To be honnest I didn't expect to be a NAT problem, because as I said this is not happenning every time.. But I'll take any tips you have ! Thanks again